# Escape string to url-fit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url-encoding

I want to escape string to be nice looking in the url.
For example white-spaces will be changed to '_'. The thing that's bother me is '%number'.. But the site has multi-languages words.

```
<%= link_to tag.name tag_details_path(tag.id,url_encode(tag.name)) %>
```

So `url_encode` doesn't fit me.

Comment: don't you have to write some custom parser, to change white-spaces to `_`?

Comment: white space to `_` is easy coding(it was an example). But I'm looking for something more wide, for example the `<`,`>` and `$` also I want to change as they can harm my URL decoding (or in general). I was sure there is a method like that in ruby, that handle URL to URL friendly..

Comment: you can use, `URI.escape("URL", /[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_\~]/)` and modify that regex to fit your needs.